# arcanist / curl is unable to make ssl connections

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, certificate, arcanist

I use phabricator and arcanist in my projects. This works well over a long time, but (after a long break i did) I'm now unable to use arcanis, if arcanist needs to connect to the phabricator-server.

Because arcanist uses cUrl for communication, this problem is probably an cUrl or SSL / CA question.

Every time, I try to connect to the server using `arc`, I get the following message:

```
 Failed to connect to server (https://my.phabricator.host/api/):
 [cURL/77] (https://my.phabricator.host/api/conduit.ping) The SSL CA
 Bundles that we tried to use could not be read or are not formatted
 correctly.
```

In the last hours, I tried different things:

1. downloading the certificate with the browser (where https to my.phabricator.host works and install the certificate to the linux/ubuntu ca-store (`/etc/ssl/certs/` / `/usr/share/ca-certificates`) using `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` and so on
2. using openssl to connect to the host/download the certificate, to test if this is possible: that works
3. trying `arc install-certificates`, which results in the same error above `The SSL CA Bundle....`
4. setting `my.phabricator.host` as blindly trust in arc-config.

...but the error still exists.

Hope to find any help or hints here.

Comment: Still not fixed? I have the same issue

Comment: I have the same issue too. I set host as blindly trust but no luck....